# Unable to change button color based on state (SOLVED)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to make a button change color when it becomes disabled while also having a custom color set when it is enabled. This is the code I have now:

The button does have blue text but even when it becomes disabled, it still stays blue. How can I make it go grey or change color when disabled?

Answer (score 1):

### Quotes are missing from your styles variable

I tested the following code on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/). The disabled button is behaving like you want:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';

const styles = theme => ({
  "& .saveButton": {
    '& :not(.Mui-disabled)': {
      color: "blue"
    }
  }
});

export default function ContainedButtons() {
  const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
      <Button variant="contained" disabled={isDisabled}>
        Disabled
      </Button>
      <Button onClick={()=>setIsDisabled(status => !status)} variant="contained">
        Toggle
      </Button>
    </Stack>
  );
}
```